# Calculating an AVG of COUNT by MONTH

Tags: sql, date, count, average

I'm trying to display the average number of counts/records for each month in 2016.  The following code does not display each month, rather displays only the monthly average for 2016:

```
SELECT      AVG(DISTINCT DayCnt) AS AvgCnt
FROM
(
    SELECT      COUNT(*) As DayCnt
    FROM        table
    WHERE       YEAR(Insert_Date) = '2016'
    GROUP BY    MONTH(Insert_Date)
)
AS AvgCnt
```

Comment: can you provide table script with sample data?

Comment: Doesn't the subquery do essentially what you want?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Some product specific SQL functions used there...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure since you didn't post the data but if I understand correctly, this should work for you:

```
SELECT      AVG(DayCnt) AS AvgCnt, mth
FROM
(
    SELECT      COUNT(*) As DayCnt, MONTH(Insert_Date) as mth
    FROM        table
    WHERE       YEAR(Insert_Date) = '2016'
    GROUP BY    MONTH(Insert_Date), DAY(Insert_Date)    )
AS AvgCnt
GROUP BY mth
```

Comment: what is diff between inner query result and outer ?

Comment: The inner query should give you the quantity of rows by day and month in 2016. The outer query should give you the average quantity of rows you received per day in a month.

Answer (score 0):

You first should be group your result per month and days and count daily inserted records, after that to get average of per month inserted records try this:

```
SELECT      monthGroup, AVG(DayCnt) AS AvgCnt
FROM
(
    SELECT      MONTH(Insert_Date) monthGroup, DAY(Insert_Date) dayGroup, COUNT(*) As DayCnt
    FROM        table
    WHERE       YEAR(Insert_Date) = '2016'
    GROUP BY    MONTH(Insert_Date), DAY(Insert_Date)
)
AS AvgCnt
GROUP BY monthGroup
```